# Decodificação em PHP de caracteres numa conexão IMAP

Tags: php, imap

## Introdução

Estou trabalhando em uma caixa de e-mails onde posteriormente terei que filtrar as mensagem por remetentes. Mas o problema está na codificação de alguns "subjects".

1. eu faço uma conexão com o servidor de e-mails através da função **imap_open**;

   ```
   $mail_box = imap_open("{" . $incoming_server . ":" . $port . "/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $username, $password) or die();
   ```
2. depois, eu pego as informações de cabeçalho através da função **imap_headerinfo**

   ```
   $header = imap_headerinfo($mail_box, $num_da_mensagem);
   ```

Entre essas duas etapas eu não manipulo nada. Tudo vem sendo triado internamente via PHP mesmo.

## Dificuldade

O problema é que quando eu dou um **print_r** nesse **$header['subject']** o retorno de alguns registros vai trazer uma string codificada assim:

```
[subject] => =?utf-8?B?UkVTOiBSRVM6IFtFWFRFUk5BTF0gUmU6IEluZm9ybWHDp8O1ZXMgc29icmUg?= =?utf-8?B?YSBBdGl2YcOnw6NvIGRvcyBQcm9kdXRvcyBlIFNlcnZpw6dvcyBDb250cmF0?= =?utf-8?Q?ados_-_WJINTERNET?=
```

Para decodificar tentei usar o **htmlentities** e outra função customizada que explico abaixo.

```
function convert_encoding ($string, $to_encoding, $from_encoding = '')  {
if ($from_encoding == '')
    $from_encoding = $this->detect_encoding($string);

if ($from_encoding == $to_encoding)
    return $string;

return mb_convert_encoding($string, $to_encoding, $from_encoding);
}

function detect_encoding($string){
if (preg_match('%^(?: [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E] | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] | \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF] | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} | \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF] | \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3} | \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2} )*$%xs', $string))
    return 'UTF-8';

return mb_detect_encoding($string, array('UTF-8', 'ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'JIS', 'EUC-JP', 'SJIS'));
}
```

Portanto, ficaria assim: convert_encoding ($header['subject'], 'UTF-8');
Mas... nada acontece. Certamente por não se tratar de uma codificação e sim de uma formatação pré-definida (suspeito). Portanto é oportuno dizer que também não entendi ainda o motivo de ter alguns registros normais e outros assim.

## O que eu preciso

1. Gostaria de saber o porquê de algumas mensagens estarem vindo com o *subject* codificado e outras não. Entender a raiz do problema pode me ajudar a enxergar um horizonte diferente para chegar em uma solução viável.
2. Caso seja um problema puramente técnico, se possível, qual técnica eu posso usar para tentar converter essa codificação para algo legível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo *subject* de e-mail que possui caracteres especiais é codificado.
São as letras acentuadas, o cedilha e etc.

Eu não sei responder exatamente o porquê dessa codificação, pois não conheço profundamente o protocolo SMTP.
Depois posso dar uma estudada a fim de melhorar essa resposta.

Existe uma função do PHP que realiza todo o trabalho pesado de decodificação.

**iconv_mime_decode**

Veja o resultado:

```
<?php
$assunto = '=?utf-8?B?UkVTOiBSRVM6IFtFWFRFUk5BTF0gUmU6IEluZm9ybWHDp8O1ZXMgc29icmUg?= =?utf-8?B?YSBBdGl2YcOnw6NvIGRvcyBQcm9kdXRvcyBlIFNlcnZpw6dvcyBDb250cmF0?= =?utf-8?Q?ados_-_WJINTERNET?=';

echo iconv_mime_decode($assunto);
?>
```

O código acima retorna:

```
RES: RES: [EXTERNAL] Re: Informações sobre a Ativação dos Produtos e Serviços Contratados - WJINTERNET
```

Referências: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.iconv-mime-decode.php

Comment: Ótimo. Aprendi mais uma. Muito obrigado por compartilhar esse conhecimento.

Também vou pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o SMTP afim de elucidar os motivos dessas codificações e se achar algo interessante acrescento aqui.